# Change column width of a Bar Chart (Google)

Tags: json, styles, google-visualization

All column widths have 1px, even if only 4 of them have data.

[image: Google Visualization API's Bar Chart]

Maybe it's a problem in the JSON I create? The rows object is gigantic: [Pastebin with the JSON](http://pastebin.com/rFsXTika)

EDIT: There's iteration in two lists. One has 27 elements and the other one has 243 elements. 9 is the actual correct number of results that must be displayed and 27*9 equals 243.

Comment: please show your javascript / chart creation code.

Comment: It's here http://pastebin.com/TxyZYFFf
I revised the code and found out I shouldn't iterate through that first list, but still the system must be prepared for a lot of data, so I won't remove this part until solving this styling issue.